# Simple regex without a regex library?

Tags: c++, c

Is there a way to know if a string ends with "goodbye" without using a regex library ?

Maybe using strcpy, strlen, ecc.

Comment: Is your string a C++ style `std::string`, or a C-style `char *`?

Comment: Since you suggested C functions, I suspect you're programming in C. As such you should remove the tag for C++ (which is a completely different language) unless you're looking for C++ answers.

Comment: @R..: in which case he should remove the C tag? ;)

Comment: boost string algos ends_with?

Comment: Indeeed, either one tag or the other should be removed for a question like this, because the answers for the two languages are very different. Tagging it both is like asking how to do the task in both Perl and Ruby... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
str.length() >= 7 && str.substr(str.length() - 7) == "goodbye"
```

Or you can use [boost::ends_with](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/ends_with.html), which is probably more efficient because it doesn't allocate a new string like `string::substr` does.

I could make the standard library version a little more efficient like this:

```
str.length() >= 7 && std::equal(str.end() - 7, str.end(), "goodbye");
```

Actually, now that I typed that out, I realize it's not as cumbersome as I thought it would be, so that should probably be preferred to the first version.

Comment: str.compare(str.length() - 7, 7, "goodbye") == 0  is also possible

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, and it takes 2 steps:

1. Use `strlen` to get the length and see if it's at least 7. If not, no match.
2. Use the length to examine the last 7 characters of the string and compare them using `strcmp`.

Comment: What fuction do I have to use to extract the last 7 characters ?
Thanks :D

Comment: More specifically, `str+len-7` points to the last 7 chars. (But this is only valid if the length is at least 7; otherwise the subtraction is out-of-bounds and results in undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    std::string a="hellogoodbye";
    size_t pos = a.rfind("goodbye");
    if(pos != string::npos && pos == a.length() - 7) std::cout << "true";
}
```

Comment: While that works, it's rather inefficient to potentially search the whole string when you're only interested in the last few characters.

Answer (score 2):

In C:

```
bool ends_with(char const * string, char const * ending) {
    size_t const slen = strlen(string);
    size_t const elen = strlen(ending);
    return slen >= elen && memcmp(string+slen-elen, ending, elen) == 0;
}
```

In C++:

```
bool ends_with(std::string const & string, std::string const & ending) {
    return string.length() >= ending.length() && 
           std::equal(ending.rbegin(), ending.rend(), string.rbegin());
}
```